# VS Code Error: "No build task to run found. Configure Build task.."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

It seems others have had the same problem, but looking through the responses it seemed that restarting the app did the trick. I have restarted the app and my computer, and there is still no change. I have had issues with VS Code in the past on my laptop, but if anyone has any idea how I can fix it that would be great!

Comment: Do you have a build task? Can you show that build task?

Comment: Obvious question but have you tried configuring a build task? What happens if you do? Do you think you have already configured one? To solve problems like this a bit of background and context is needed. Just quoting an error message does not diagnose a problem.

Comment: You probably want to start with this tutorial from Microsoft that explains the 3 json files that are used: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: My original task wasn't working so I just switched to a simple "hello world" task and it still isn't working.                                                                                            
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "hello world." << endl;
    return 0;
}